# AngularJS: How to access node request parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using angular to deal with some routes, namely a home and a landing page. However, after the user logins, I want to be able to access the user parameter attached to the req object.

Generally, in express, that means rendering the page after a get request like this

```
app.get('/home'... {user: req.user})
```

And then accessing `<%= req.user %>` inside the ejs template.

However, in angular, I'm using ui-router to open the pages like thus

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('home',{
            url: '/home', 
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl', //initializes with this ctrl, no need to specify earlier
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                    return posts.getAll();
                }]
            }
        });
        $stateProvider.state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl',
            resolve: {
                post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts){
                    return posts.get($stateParams.id);
                }]
            }
        });
        $stateProvider.state('landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            templateUrl: '/landing.html',
            controller: 'landCtrl',
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');//otherwise go here
    }]);
```

I've been unable to access the req.user object after the user logins. I need to do so for some conditional executions. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you need to access the user object on the client side(Angular) or you need a way to make sure req.user is always there on the server if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [sharify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharify) which is an npm package that allows you to send some server-side data down to your browser code by way of a `<script>` tag with some JSON inside it. Follow the tutorials, I usually end up setting the user as a constant in the angular app:

```
myapp.constant('user', sharify.data.user);
```